# DualShock 4 Controller Speaker Access

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, controller

Is there any way to route sound through an individual controller, i.e. play sound A in situation X from controller A and sound B in situation X from controller B?

A questions asking the same thing exists, but it is four years old, so I'm asking again. The person in the old question was using Rewired to access most of the DualShock 4 features, except for the sound, which is not yet possible in Rewired, as far as I have seen in the current documentation. Is there another way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity only supports generic controller functionality, like analog input and button input, but does not have native support for what you want. For specific functionality like audio playing from a DUALSHOCK®4 controller, you'll need the appropriate devkit access and licensing.

If you have a Unity PS4 license, there's built-in Unity support for what you want. As a PS4 developer, I've accessed features like the speaker and lightbar quite easily in the past. Note, however, these features won't work on PC, as there are no drivers for a DUALSHOCK®4 controller that works outside of the PS4 environment.